# WCF - AddressFilter mismatch

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a self-hosted WCF service, and am getting the following exception when calling it:

> The message with To 'net.tcp://localhost:53724/Test1' cannot be
>   processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the
>   EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's
>   EndpointAddresses agree.

The solution that works is to add `[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Prefix)]` before the service interface's implementation class. But that shouldn't be the case! So, I'm trying to get to the source of the error in order to remove it.

I've found that 
When I do add the `ServiceBehavior` attribute and the call succeeds - the following: `OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress`
Returns: `net.tcp://localhost/Test1` - notice the absence of the port. That is actually what I feed the `ServiceHost.Open` method. But the port is added because I specify `ListenUriMode.Unique` .

So: How do I fix the error with `AddressFilterMode.Exact` ?

**Code to reproduce:**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCF1
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool SendMessage(string message);
}

[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Prefix)]
public class WCF1 : IWCF1
{
    public bool SendMessage(string message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Message: " + message);
        Debug.WriteLine(OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress, "EndpointAddress");//Does not include the port!
        return true;
    }
}


public void test()
{
    Uri uri2 = Service(typeof(WCF1), typeof(IWCF1), "Test1");
    IWCF1 iwcf1 = CreateChannel(uri2.ToString());
    new Task(() => iwcf1.SendMessage("abc")).Start();
}

public Uri Service(Type class1, Type interface1, string uri)
{
    string serviceUri = "net.tcp://localhost/" + uri;
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(class1, new Uri(serviceUri));
    ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(interface1, new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), serviceUri);
    ep.ListenUriMode = ListenUriMode.Unique;
    host.Open();
    return host.ChannelDispatchers[0].Listener.Uri;
}

public static IWCF1 CreateChannel(string address)
{
    EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress(address);
    ChannelFactory<IWCF1> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IWCF1>(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), ep);
    return channelFactory.CreateChannel();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the source of the `AddressFilterMode.Exact` error involves the difference between the logical endpoint and physical service address.

The `EndpointAddress` is the logical address of a service, which is the address that SOAP messages are addressed to. The `ListenUri` is the physical address of the service. It has the port and address information where the service endpoint actually listens for messages on the current machine.  The logical endpoint address, not the physical service location, is used for by the dispatcher for matching and filtering, thus the reason why an exact match does not find the service.

The Physical Address is not the same as the Logical Address:

```
  net.tcp://localhost:53724/Test1  !=  net.tcp://localhost/Test1
```

A few options to consider:
Continue to use `AddressFilterMode.Prefix`
Try specifying `HostNameComparisonMode`
Specify the port in advance

References:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395210%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163412.aspx#S4

Comment: Accepting as answer. But it would be nice to have some source for this.

Comment: The second reference is now only available as a .chm download ( http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A7FA450-1F33-41F7-9E6D-3AA95B5A6AEA/MSDNMagazineJune2007en-us.chm ). I don't know whether it's better to replace the link with that or with an archive.org one.