# What are the implications of AddressFilterMode.Prefix (or Any)?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Since [I can't seem to find a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852554/wcf-addressfilter-mismatch) for overcoming an **AddressFilter** mismatch with `AddressFilterMode.Exact`,  I'd like to know what does `AddressFilterMode.Prefix` really mean.

Is it safely ignored? What's the case where there will be an error because **AddressFilterMode** isn't `Exact`?

Answer (score 0):

The `ServiceBehavior` `AddressFilterMode.Prefix` attribute is commonly used when the logical endpoint address does not match the physical service address (listen uri).  When the logical and physical addresses do not match, the `AddressFilterMode.Exact` will not find a corresponding endpoint.

For example, my team recently worked on system that used "routing codes" (urn://abc) as the logical endpoint addresses rather than the physical address for filtering and routing.